# How does one center-align a button using Materialize CSS?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I can't seem to find any documentation on the Materialize website regarding positioning of elements. Can anyone help me center this button? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="div">

    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>Enter</a>

</div>

#div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to center the button inside of?

Comment: Just a regular full width `div`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Vertical Alignment:** 
Use a wrapper and give the wrapper a class of `.valign-wrapper`

```
<div class="valign-wrapper">
  <h5>This should be vertically aligned</h5>
</div>
```

**Horizontal Alignment:**
Use `.left-align`, `.right-align`, `.center-align` on the element to be centered.

See [documentation](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html).

Comment: Also, do you know how to position the button with `px`? My CSS does not seem to be having any effect.

Comment: @LordGoderick Not sure what you mean.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: As in I want to nudge the button by `20px` to the left for example. Where would I override the original CSS?

Comment: @LordGoderick Adding an id to the anchor tag and targeting that with `margin-right:20px` would be the easiest way.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I did that before I asked you and it didn't work. But now it suddenly works, probably clumsy mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You can center the button using materialize class center-align, but use it on `<p>` or `<div>` tag. since `<a>` tag is inline-block tag.

Here is the code.

```
<p class="center-align">
 <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>Enter</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Add 'center' class to the surrounding div:**

```
<div id="div" class="row center">
   <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue"><i class="material-icons 
   right">cloud</i>Enter</a>
</div>
```

Note - div must also have the 'row' class.